# Can this textbook question on angular magnification be answered without a ruler?

Tags: optics, imaging

This is a textbook question on angular magnification from [a chapter](https://www.hoddereducation.co.uk/getattachment/7c432a55-adfa-46de-b9ad-d4e9390da695/Physics-Option-C.pdf?lang=en-GB&ext=.pdf) on optics and imaging.  Note that this comprehension check comes before telescopes are introduced.

> **12** Figure 15.12 [below] shows a partial eclipse of the Sun.
>
> [image]
>
> **a** What angle does this image of the Sun subtend at
>   your eye when it is at the near point of your eye?
>
> **b** The Sun has a diameter of $1.4\times10^6\:\mathrm{km}$ and it is $1.5\times10^8\:\mathrm{km}$ from Earth. What is the angular magnification of Figure 15.12?

Note that

> Angular magnification, $M$, is defined as the angle subtended at the eye by the image, $\theta_\mathrm{i}$, divided by the angle subtended at the eye by the object, $\theta_\mathrm{o}$. $\displaystyle M=\frac{\theta_\mathrm{i}}{\theta_\mathrm{o}}$.

and that

> If the lens is moved to obtain the largest clear image, the image will be formed at the near point and the angular magnification can be determined from $\displaystyle M_{\text{near point}} = \frac Df+1$

where $D = 25\:\mathrm{cm}$ is the distance to a normal eye’s near point. The question also comes right before this diagram of simple magnification:

> [image: Fig 15.11 simple magnification]

**Is it possible to answer these two questions without measuring the height of the image shown in Figure 15.12, or is it necessary to do so?**

*Edit:* It is easy for me to see that the (planar) visual angle $\psi$ subtended by a linear object of of length $l$ whose centre is a distance $d$ from the eye is $\displaystyle \psi = \arctan\frac d{2l}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for part a you need to measure the diameter of the image in millimetres and then divide it by the near point distance (250 mm).